# Modify didSelectRowAtIndexPath for StoryBoard Usage, IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {

NSMutableArray *petsArray;
}

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *petsArray;

    @end
```

RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "PetsViewController.h"

    @interface RootViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation RootViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

petsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[petsArray addObject:@"Dog"];
[petsArray addObject:@"Cat"];
[petsArray addObject:@"Snake"];
[self setTitle:@"PETS !"];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this     view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [petsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate
```

I think that the problem is in didSelectRowAtIndexPath which I can't use in storyboarded project.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
PetsViewController *pets = [[PetsViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"PetsViewController" bundle:nil];

```
if ([[petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Dog"]) {
    pets.petsInt = 0;
    [pets setTitle:[petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

if ([[petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Cat"]) {
    pets.petsInt = 1;
    [pets setTitle:[petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

if ([[petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Snake"]) {
    pets.petsInt = 2;
    [pets setTitle:[petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:pets animated:YES];

}

    @end
```

PetsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PetsViewController : UITableViewController {
NSMutableArray *dogArray;
NSMutableArray *catArray;
NSMutableArray *snakeArray;
int petsInt;
}

@property int petsInt;

@end
```

PetsViewController.m

```
#import "PetsViewController.h"

@interface PetsViewController ()

@end

@implementation PetsViewController
@synthesize petsInt;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

dogArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"HAF",@"hafo", @"hafinio", nil];
catArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"MYAU",@"myainio", @"mya lya lya",  nil];
snakeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"fshhhhh",@"fsssss", @"xrt", nil];



}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.

if (petsInt == 0) return [dogArray count];
if (petsInt == 1) return [catArray count];
if (petsInt == 2) return [snakeArray count];

[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PetsCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
if (petsInt == 0) cell.textLabel.text = [dogArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (petsInt == 1) cell.textLabel.text = [catArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (petsInt == 2) cell.textLabel.text = [snakeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

return cell;
}



#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc]    initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 */
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SEGUE_NAME" sender:self];


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SEGUE_NAME"]) {
        PetsViewController *pets = [segue destinationViewController];

        [pets setPetsInt:0];
        [pets setTitle:@"Title"];
    }
}
```

Comment: i need that when dog array is taped storyboard load @"HAF",@"hafo,hafinio", and when taped cat array it loads @"MYAU",@"myainio", @"mya lya lya"

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;

if ([[gazel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"<էրեբունի> Օդանավակայան"]) {
    KangarList *kang = [segue destinationViewController];
    kang.kangarInt = 0;
    [kang setTitle:[gazel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

if ([[gazel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"<էրեբունի> Օդանավակայան"]) {
    KangarList *kang = [segue destinationViewController];
    kang.kangarInt = 1;
    [kang setTitle:[gazel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

if ([[gazel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"<էրեբունի> Օդանավակայան"]) {
    KangarList *kang = [segue destinationViewController];
    kang.kangarInt = 2;
    [kang setTitle:[gazel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

if ([[gazel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"<էրեբունի> Օդանավակայան"]) {
    KangarList *kang = [segue destinationViewController];
    kang.kangarInt = 3;
    [kang setTitle:[gazel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
}
```

i have tried many ways and i finaly realized the right method, but it works only when under  view did load method objects have only one description but if it hase something like thise

```
gazel = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Data *data = [[Data alloc] init];
data.title = @"<էրեբունի> Օդանավակայան";
data.subtitle = @"Հարաֆ Արևմտյան Թաղամաս";
data.photo = 1;
[gazel addObject:data];
```

its not working